# How to decode the following encoded email id>

Tags: asp.net

can anyone have idea to decode the following encode email id?
email_address="72ee33d86d5749711fe335d62d0671fa02120d54215f5744353d4164020959" .

Also how to encrypt the same to protect it securedly?

Answer (score 0):

You should try multiple decrypters and hope that there is one that is able to decrypt it. Some decrypters only work if these set of characters are already encrypted before.

You could try using the following Cryptographic algorithms:

- DES
- RSA
- HASH
- MD5
- Base64
- AES
- SHA-1
- HMAC

Note: A good Cryptographic algorithm turns the data into truly opaque, meaning that it's impossible to decrypt it without the key.

Answer (score 0):

if you looking to do the decryption, you can go take a look at this site http://www.dcode.fr/tous-les-outils (in French) which has a huge range of tools

Also look at this topic https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used